# Softlayer API get open ports

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am working with the Softlayer API to get data on Virtual Guests and Hardware Servers. I want to find a way to get open ports, i.e. to find out if port 80, or 3306, or custom ports are open on the server.

I cannot seem to find a way to do this through the API. I've dug down into many calls, servers, firewalls, routers, networks etc.

Is this possible through the API? I am not seeing this information in control.softlayer.com either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not possible to get that information through API and [Control Portal](https://control.softlayer.com/). You should check them inside your server.